# Как растянуть backrground image?

Tags: html, css

Коллеги, добрый день. Появилась проблема, background image секции расстягивается не полностью,у одной секции встал как надо, а у другой секции он выходит не во всю ширину. Ниже покажу все на скриншотах. Секция что снизу встала как надо, а секция сверху расстягивает изображение, в чем причина? Код идентичный. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.about-us {
background-image: url('../img/about-us.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
padding: 100px 0px;
}

.how {
padding: 100px 0px;
background-image: url('../img/how.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
```

Добавлю, что ширина у обоих картинок одинаковая, но отображаются они по разному

UPD: Решил экспортом двух картинок, объединенными в одну

Comment: Попробуй указать сайз в процентах

Comment: height: 100% не увенчался успехами

Comment: Background-size: 100% 100%;

Comment: Но тогда картинка будет узкой на мобильных устройствах, а мне нужно чтоб она растягивалась, тоесть была cover

Comment: Для начала не стоит такие картинки грузить через css - это же динамические элементы. Вдруг заменить придётся изображение, что в css лезть будете? А если вы уже проект отдадите заказчику и он захочет каждую неделю менять изображение, он будет к вам обращаться, что бы вы поправили css?

Answer (score 2):

Адаптировать для мобильных устройств можно следующим образом:

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {

.how {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

}
```

Блок @media создается не вместо, а отдельно от существующего блока, и применяется только когда условие выполнено. В данном случае условие - max-width: 900px . Поэкспериментируете и подберите нужное Вам условие.

Условия можно комбинировать. Вот пример:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 900px) {

.how {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

}
```

Или можно создать условие для экрана:

```
@media screen (min-width: 900px) {

.how {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

}
```